# Highcharts error 15

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm trying to represent these data using highcharts:

```
[
  {
    "name": "c1",
    "data": [
      [
        -52587360000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52590038400000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52611724800000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52622611200000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52655184000000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52663392000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52855545600000,
        2
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "c2",
    "data": [
      [
        -52587360000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52590038400000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52611724800000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52622611200000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52655184000000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52663392000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52855545600000,
        2
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "c3",
    "data": [
      [
        -52587360000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52590038400000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52611724800000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52622611200000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52655184000000,
        1
      ],
      [
        -52663392000000,
        2
      ],
      [
        -52855545600000,
        2
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what i try:

```
container.highcharts({
    title: {
        text:"Name"
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Occurrence'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'Occurrence'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: response // 
});
```

The chart isn't shown correctly as you can see:
[image]
and in console i get this error:

```
"Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15"
```

what is my error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the [link in the error message](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) will tell you:

> **Highcharts expects data to be sorted**
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

In your case the x-values in your first series are:

```
-52587360000000
-52590038400000
-52611724800000
-52622611200000
-52655184000000
-52663392000000
-52855545600000
```

Just looking at the first two it is clear that `-52587360000000` is a smaller (more negative) number than `-52590038400000`. It appears that you have in fact reverse-sorted them. That is, the largest number is first, then they get increasingly smaller (more negative).

You will have to change the order of the data in the series so that the smallest number is first and then the values increase.

Comment: Happens when staring at the same code for too long :)

Comment: What if we have values plotted against the years so we cannot sort the value and pass it inside the graph.we need to show the corresponding value against the years..so in that we cannot avoid the same error?.

Answer (score 7):

This issue occurs when you sort the date order by desc

**Note**

- Do not sort the data order by date desc
- Instead sort the data order by date Asc

Your issue will be resolved. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the first element of the "data array" , is datetime-descend.
this is incorrect for HiChart. e.g.

```
# this sort cause error 15 of highchart
[   5,        'content...' ],
[   4,        'content...' ],
[   3,        'content...' ]
```

solution: re-order the array with the 'asend order' for the first element, e.g.

```
# this is working good
[   3,        'content...' ],
[   4,        'content...' ],
[   5,        'content...' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort your data :

data : [your data].sort()