# Highcharts xAxis date issue on Safari or Chrome for Ipad

Tags: javascript, highcharts, momentjs, mobile-safari

I'm having an issue displaying date on highcharts on Safari or Chrome for IPad.

Using the following code to set the format:

```
// Convert sharepoint date to MMM YYYY format
    for (i = 0; i < customerSortedData.length; i++) {
        if (moment(customerSortedData[i].Date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss", 'br', true).isValid()) 
        {
            customerSortedData[i].MonthYear = moment(customerSortedData[i].Date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss", 'br', true).format('MMM YYYY');
        }
    }
```

, it shows correctly on windows Chrome browser, like 'Apr 2017', 'May 2017'.....'Feb 2018', 'Mar 2018".

The same chart on IPad shows: 'Aug 2017', 'Feb 2018', 'Dec 2017', 'Oct 2017', 'Jan 2018', 'Apr 2017' and then 'Invalid date'. It is expected to show last 12 months in order, but it shows 6 dates only.

Could you please help me to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Just tested on Android and it works fine. The problem must be on IOS.

Comment: It was deprecated issue on moment.js. Just convert the date to string right before sent to highcharts works.

Answer (score 0):

If your `customerSortedData` array is not sorted by `customerSortedData.Date` , it could be the source of the problem. Highcharts needs the x values to be sorted.

See this question for further details : [Highcharts error 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082034/highcharts-error-15)

Comment: Actually I'm sorting by date as well. I'm not sure if the arrow (=>) from ES6 may be the problem. Does you know if Safari / Chrome for Ipad supports ES6 or only ES5?

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry